# React native places autocomplete

Tags: react-native

I want to create a google places autocomplete for my React Native.
I want to create full custom TextInput and Results.
I want it to be entirely up to me, without third-party dependencies.
What is the most professional way to create this?

Comment: As a  working  software engineer I recommend to use 3rd party library . If  you are creating your own project . But if you really want to do this you can take reference of this blog  : https://medium.com/@hamzaqaisrani/using-the-google-maps-places-autocomplete-javascript-api-in-a-react-project-5742bab4abc9

Comment: Nice, thank you very much for your reply, I will read it.